# Entity with one to many does not add new children when updated

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have the following entity

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Audited(modifiedColumnName = "children_modified")
    private List<Children> children;
    ...
}
```

And, when I add a new children, I do the following:

```
parent.addChild(new Child(parent, "child1"))
parentService.updateParent(parent)
```

The repository method, only calls to the parentRepository.save (spring-data-jpa).

Then, after that service call, I can see that the parent has a child entity and that that entity has an id.

Then, later on, I add a new child, same procedure:

```
parent.addChild(new Child(parent, "child2"))
parentService.updateParent(parent)
```

But then, the second children does not have an id set. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show the code of parent.addChild?

Comment: public void addChild(Child child) {
        if (this.children == null) {
            this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.children.add(child);
    }

Comment: Do you set the applicant field?

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli, I updated the question. Yes, I set it, by new Child(parent, "child2")

Comment: The save method is returning the saved entity. Do you use this to add the second child?